# How to specify the common module version in the multi-project Gradle build

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to define version only in the root build script, so that all the sub-projects are using the same version? But don't pull modules into sub-projects which don't use those modules.

For example:
root.build.gradle

```
com.company:module-A:version-A
com.company:module-B:version-B
com.company:module-C:version-C
```

sub-project-1.build.gradle

```
   com.company:module-A
   com.company:module-B
```

sub-project-2.build.gradle

```
   com.company:module-A
   com.company:module-C
```

After build, only module-A.version-A and module-B.version-B are in the distribution of sub-project-1, and module-A.version-A and module-C.version-C are in the distribution of sub-project-2.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, they differ where you hold the information which subprojects depend on the common module.

**Solution 1:**
Store the common version in the root project, then declare dependencies in subprojects using it.

root project:

```
ext {
    commonModuleDependency = "com.company:module-A:version-A"
}
```

subproject:

```
dependencies {
    compile rootProject.commonModuleDependency
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Configure the subprojects from the root project.
In this case the root project knows which subprojects have the common dependency.

root project:

```
subprojects.findAll {
    it.name in listOfSubprojectsThatHaveCommonModule
}.configure {
    dependencies {
        compile "com.company:module-A:version-A"
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you try the first one, because it is arguably simpler and less coupled...
I feel you really want to first and foremost solve the problem of not having different versions of the same dependency anywhere, right?

Comment: Yes. I think solution 1 is better for me

Comment: @Wang Wei, Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you, thanks!